# How to center menu that is stretced from the side

Tags: html, css

I need to place the menu in the center. The problem is that the menu is stretched from the side. Here is an idea of the menu:
http://filebeam.com/c7bc3829dff04ab6217bd7ae8b8ed68b.jpg

So, i don't have any idea how to fill left part of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this CORRECTED jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRrhv/

The key is to have both `.menu-container` and `.menu` set to the same width and make sure
to add `margin:auto` to the `.menu-container` class to center everything.

Cheers!

Comment: According to a link, it's a bit a different solution. I need to center menu, that have a gap at the left that is filled with a background.

Comment: Nope, link is still the same.

Comment: GAH! Ok, I created a *new* jsFiddle. I've checked it in every browser and it *is* centered now :)